# How to Convert Stream Stream<HashMap<String, Object>> to HashMap Array HashMap<String, Object>[]?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am newbie in Java 8 Streams. Please advice, how to Convert Stream `Stream<HashMap<String, Object>>` to HashMap Array `HashMap<String, Object>[]` ?

For example, I has some stream in code:

```
Stream<String> previewImagesURLsList = fileNames.stream();

Stream<HashMap<String, Object>> imagesStream = previewImagesURLsList
    .map(new Function<String, HashMap<String, Object>>() {
        @Override
        public HashMap<String, Object> apply(String person) {
            HashMap<String, Object> m = new HashMap<>();
            m.put("dfsd", person);
            return m;
        }
    });
```

How I can do something like

```
HashMap<String, Object>[] arr = imagesStream.toArray();
```

?

Sorry my bad English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following should work. Unfortunately, you have to suppress the *unchecked* warning.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
HashMap<String, Object>[] arr = imagesStream.toArray(HashMap[]::new);
```

The expression `HashMap[]::new` is an *array constructor reference*, which is a kind of *method reference*. *Method references* provide an alternative way to implement functional interfaces. You can also use a lambda expression:

```
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"})
HashMap<String, Object>[] array = stream.toArray(n -> new HashMap[n]);
```

Before Java 8, you would have used an *anonymous inner class* for that purpose.

```
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"})
HashMap<String, Object>[] array = stream.toArray(new IntFunction<HashMap[]>() {
    public HashMap[] apply(int n) {
        return new HashMap[n];
    }
});
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much **nosid** for my saved time!

Comment: But what imagesStream.toArray(HashMap[]::new) means? Is it lambda? Can you send me full form of the imagesStream.toArray(HashMap[]::new), without lambda?